# Python - __eq__ method not being called

Tags: python

I have a set of objects, and am interested in getting a specific object from the set.  After some research, I decided to use the solution provided here:  http://code.activestate.com/recipes/499299/

The problem is that it doesn't appear to be working.

I have two classes defined as such:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    def __key(self):
        return (self.a, self.b, self.c)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__key() == other.__key()
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__key())

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self.e = e
```

Note:  equality of these two classes should only be defined on the attributes a, b, c.

The wrapper `_CaptureEq` in http://code.activestate.com/recipes/499299/ also defines its own `__eq__` method.  The problem is that this method never gets called (I think).  Consider,

```
bar_1 = Bar(1,2,3,4,5)
bar_2 = Bar(1,2,3,10,11)
summary = set((bar_1,))
assert(bar_1 == bar_2)
bar_equiv = get_equivalent(summary, bar_2)
```

`bar_equiv.d` should equal 4 and likewise `bar_equiv .e` should equal 5, but they are not.  Like I mentioned, it looks like the `__CaptureEq` `__eq__` method does not get called when the statement `bar_2 in summary` is executed.

Is there some reason why the `__CaptureEq` `__eq__` method is not being called?  Hopefully this is not too obscure of a question.

Comment: How are you determining that the method isn't called? Just because the result isn't what you expect? Did you try tracing it?

Comment: Yeah, it isn't called... odd.

Comment: For me it was because I used `attr` and set `@attrs.s` decorator for my class and my `__eq__` gets overwritten by `attr`, hopefully someone doesn't make the same silly mistake as I did

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Brandon's answer is informative, but incorrect. There are actually two problems, one with 
the recipe relying on `_CaptureEq` being written as an old-style class (so it won't work properly if you try it on Python 3 with a hash-based container), and one with your own `Foo.__eq__` definition claiming definitively that the two objects are not equal when it should be saying "I don't know, ask the other object if we're equal".

The recipe problem is trivial to fix: just define `__hash__` on the comparison wrapper class:

```
class _CaptureEq:
    'Object wrapper that remembers "other" for successful equality tests.'
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        self.match = obj
    # If running on Python 3, this will be a new-style class, and
    # new-style classes must delegate hash explicitly in order to populate
    # the underlying special method slot correctly.
    # On Python 2, it will be an old-style class, so the explicit delegation
    # isn't needed (__getattr__ will cover it), but it also won't do any harm.
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.obj)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        result = (self.obj == other)
        if result:
            self.match = other
        return result
    def __getattr__(self, name):  # support anything else needed by __contains__
        return getattr(self.obj, name)
```

The problem with your own `__eq__` definition is also easy to fix: return `NotImplemented` when appropriate so you aren't claiming to provide a definitive answer for comparisons with unknown objects:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    def __key(self):
        return (self.a, self.b, self.c)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Foo):
            # Don't recognise "other", so let *it* decide if we're equal
            return NotImplemented
        return self.__key() == other.__key()
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__key())
```

With those two fixes, you will find that Raymond's `get_equivalent` recipe works exactly as it should:

```
>>> from capture_eq import *
>>> bar_1 = Bar(1,2,3,4,5)
>>> bar_2 = Bar(1,2,3,10,11)
>>> summary = set((bar_1,))
>>> assert(bar_1 == bar_2)
>>> bar_equiv = get_equivalent(summary, bar_2)
>>> bar_equiv.d
4
>>> bar_equiv.e
5
```

**Update:** Clarified that the explicit `__hash__` override is only needed in order to correctly handle the Python 3 case.

Comment: Given that `_CaptureEq` is an old-style class, why are you adding a method with a comment that talks about new-style classes? You can verify with a `print` statement that `__getattr__()` was returning functions just fine, I believe.

Comment: But, good job on pointing out that the guy who sees himself being compared to the `_CaptureEq` instance can just refuse to do the comparison — I always forget how those fall-through cases work because I never override operators myself.

Comment: If you want it to work on Python 3 as well, you need to force the `__hash__` delegation. I'll update the comment.

Comment: @Brandon Even with new-style classes, `__getattr__` can be used to correctly delegate method lookups. It's only *special method* lookups that need to be overridden explicitly in order to fill out the correct entries in the internal fast lookup table for the type (for CPython, that's a bunch of C level function pointers stored on the type object).

Comment: FWIW, failing to return `NotImplemented` for unknown types is probably the single most common bug when overriding binary operators in Python. It typically only gets discovered when someone tries to reuse the type outside its original context.

Comment: Oh — and one *returns* `NotImplemented` instead of raising it? Craziness :)

Comment: The overhead of exceptions is too high to be usable for this purpose, hence why `NotImplemented` is distinct from `NotImplementedError` :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the `set` compares two objects the “wrong way around” for this pattern to intercept the call to `__eq__()`. The recipe from 2006 evidently was written against containers that, when asked if `x` was present, went through the candidate `y` values already present in the container doing:

```
x == y
```

comparisons, in which case an `__eq__()` on `x` could do special actions during the search. But the `set` object is doing the comparison the other way around:

```
y == x
```

for each y in the set. Therefore this pattern might simply not be usable in this form when your data type is a `set`. You can confirm this by instrumenting `Foo.__eq__()` like this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    print '__eq__: I am', self.d, self.e, 'and he is', other.d, other.e
    return self.__key() == other.__key()
```

You will then see a message like:

```
__eq__: I am 4 5 and he is 10 11
```

confirming that the equality comparison is posing the equality question to the object *already in the set* — which is, alas, *not* the object wrapped with Hettinger's `_CaptureEq` object.

**Update:**

And I forgot to suggest a way forward: have you thought about using a dictionary? Since you have an idea here of a key that is a subset of the data inside the object, you might find that splitting out the idea of the key from the idea of the object itself might alleviate the need to attempt this kind of convoluted object interception. Just write a new function that, given an object and your dictionary, computes the key and looks in the dictionary and returns the object already in the dictionary if the key is present else inserts the new object at the key.

**Update 2:** well, look at that — Nick's answer uses a `NotImplemented` in one direction to *force* the `set` to do the comparison in the other direction. Give the guy a few +1's!

Comment: it should be `set((bar_1,))` - question is valid, but some errors in the code (fixed a couple of problems myself already)

Comment: Another solution might be to turn `_CaptureEq` into a subclass of `Bar` - that would ensure that `y == x` calls `x.__eq__(y)` first.

Comment: @Brandon - that's just it, I want the value of the object in the set.  The recipe appears to work with sets on the trivial example given its documentation, i.e.,  >>> get_equivalent(set([1, 2, 3]), 2.0) # 2.0 is equivalent to 2.  Thanks for the insight...

Comment: No need for any radical changes - the definition of `Foo.__eq__` is just buggy and needs to be fixed to avoid breaking the recipe. See my answer for a version that works as requested.

Answer (score -2):

There are two issues here. The first is that:

```
t = _CaptureEq(item)
if t in container:
    return t.match
return default
```

Doesn't do what you think. In particular, `t` will *never* be in `container`, since `_CaptureEq` doesn't define `__hash__`. This becomes more obvious in Python 3, since it will point this out to you rather than providing a default `__hash__`. The code for `_CaptureEq` seems to believe that providing an `__getattr__` will solve this - it won't, since Python's special method lookups are not guaranteed to go through all the same steps as normal attribute lookups - this is the same reason `__hash__` (and various others) need to be defined on a class and can't be monkeypatched onto an instance. So, the most direct way around this is to define `_CaptureEq.__hash__` like so:

```
def __hash__(self):
   return hash(self.obj)
```

But that still isn't guaranteed to work, because of the second issue: `set` lookup is not guaranteed to test equality. `set`s are based on hashtables, and only do an equality test if there's more than one item in a hash bucket. You can't (and don't want to) force items that hash differently into the same bucket, since that's all an implementation detail of `set`. The easiest way around this issue, and to neatly sidestep the first one, is to use a list instead:

```
summary = [bar_1]
assert(bar_1 == bar_2)
bar_equiv = get_equivalent(summary, bar_2)
assert(bar_equiv is bar_1)
```

Comment: If you will add some `print` statements you will see that `__hash__` is indeed being looked up through the `__getattr__` and that the lookup is indeed successful, because the `_CaptureEq` is an old-style class. Yes, I know—Raymond Hettinger used an old-style class to better wrap something more completely than is possible today! He is a crazy, crazy guy.

Comment: This is incorrect. In fact `__getattr__` does solve the hashing problem by deferring to `self.obj.__hash__`, and `set` lookup **is** guaranteed to test equality **when the hashes match**. Hashes **must** differ for unequal objects, but they *can* match for unequal objects, so each "hash bucket" in principle can contain arbitrarily many objects with the same hash, and possibly none of them are actually the object being looked up, so each must be tested for equality. `__hash__ = lambda x: 1` is a technically-correct hash function, it's just not a useful one.

Comment: @Ben is absolutely correct: since all sorts of objects can share the same hash, a set *must* perform an equality check before returning `True` to an `in` test. Only if the test finds the hashes unequal can it short-circuit and assume that the objects themselves are unequal without a further test.

Comment: @BrandonRhodes ah, you learn something new every day. The difference will old-style classes will teach me to have Py2 around for testing these things, and sets testing equality more often than I thought seems amazingly obvious in hindsight. I suppose that does me for new stuff for two days... or at least one and a half.

Comment: I must admit that today is the day that I myself also learned this about old-style classes — if I ever knew this in years past, I had certainly forgotten until I added the `print` statement a few minutes go as I tried to figure out the order in which these methods were being called! We should tell Raymond that he is too obscure. :)

Comment: @BrandonRhodes if I'd noticed the recipe was from Raymond, I probably would have paused for longer before jumping to "the author is making assumptions that don't hold".